# Can ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem execute on Main Thread?

Tags: c#, silverlight, macos, threadpool, queueuserworkitem

I'm trying to tackle a weird issue on SL on the Mac in a multi-threaded application. My application employs the ThreadPool to queue various different work items. I have a method `HandleRequest` that is only called via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleRequest))`.

The application was running very slowly so I remote debugged from Windows and paused it to find a bunch of threads stuck in HandleRequest because they were waiting on a limited resource. That is fine, as there's another issue there, but I also noticed that there was a HandleRequest waiting in the Main thread. How can that happen? I thought ThreadPool created worker threads in the background and executed the tasks on them.

Is this happening because the ThreadPool has run out of worker threads and is thus using the calling thread to try and execute the callback method?

Comment: `ThreadPool` creates independent set of threads for work item processing. The call stack on the Main thread should tell you where it was called from.

Comment: Does the `HandleRequest` method have any `Dispatcher.Invoke` calls? Such calls would always be executed synchronously on the main thread.

Comment: @Douglas The `HandleRequest`'s state object contains a callback which may contain `Dispatcher.Invoke` calls. I guess that's why the work item is being scheduled in the main thread... since I execute the callback at the end of `HandleRequest`?

Comment: Yes, that is a possible explanation. During the `Dispatcher.Invoke` call, the worker thread is blocked, and (execution) control transferred to the main thread. Control transfers back to the worker thread when the `Invoke` delegate completes.